# Python opencv detecting chessboard

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to get the corners of a chessboard pattern, and thought I could use openCV with `cv2.findChessboardCorners`.

However, I can't find the good arguments to pass to the function such that it succeeds in detecting the chessboard. I thought the image would be appropriated for this function. If it is not, I can't figure out what king of preprocessing I should do ..

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import sys
import os

nline = 4
ncol = 4 

img = cv2.imread(glob.glob('*.jpg')[0])

## termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

## processing
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find the chessboard corners
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (nline, ncol), None)
corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
```

and this is the image :[image]

I have tried various pattern size to give him, because I thought that a 4*4 pattern would be easier to find but it wan not.

EDIT : Actually using the appropriated number of lines and columns its works :
[image]

However, it doesn't for these ones which are not so different from the first one ...  [image] 11 lines, for 8 or 9 columns, tried both.

Or this one : [image] which is 13*9.

How to deal with this kind of images ?

Answer (score 3):

Parameters `nline` and `ncol` must be exact, (number of rows -1, number colums -1)

```
nline = 11
ncol = 9
```

Comment: I actually never thought it had to be exact ! Thanks !

Comment: Actually sometimes it is hard to determine the exact number of row and lines, see edit of the topic. I also tried to crop the image to make it more clear but it did not succeed ...

Comment: From [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga93efa9b0aa890de240ca32b11253dd4a): "The function requires white space (like a square-thick border, the wider the better) around the board to make the detection more robust in various environments. Otherwise, if there is no border and the background is dark, the outer black squares cannot be segmented properly and so the square grouping and ordering algorithm fails. "

Comment: I tried to crop the chessboard, setting all background to 255, but it didn't succeed either. I will keep investigating this, thanks for your help.